# Multiple destination domains per transaction is unsupported

Tags: email

Email Log:

```
Mar  6 09:39:26 mail sendmail[31590]: v264cTSt031481: to=user1@gmail.com, ctladdr=<software-auto@example.com> (564/564), delay=00:00:56, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=321130, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.206.27], dsn=4.3.0, stat=Deferred: 451-4.3.0 Multiple destination domains per transaction is unsupported.  Please
```

I am facing this Problem and need some kind of solution. i am trying to googling it also.
I am using Sendmail in CentOS Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google email relay – Multiple destination domains per transaction is unsupported

Those experiencing this problem when trying to send batches of emails through the google’s multiple MX records (aspmx.l.google.com , alt1.aspmx.l.google.com , …) , here are some workarounds.

In this case scenario we will assume we are using CentOS and sendmail as our method.

Segregate different domain emails to be sent through a separate  sendmail session (this is usually done in your code)
Relay everything through the smtp.gmail.com
Configure sendmail to delivery to each email on one connection.
On you sendmail.mc add these following line

```
define(`SMTP_MAILER_MAXRCPTS', `1')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_MAXRCPTS', `1')dnl
The above lines MUST be added before

MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl
After that save your .mc and m4 it to your .cf

m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
Restart sendmail and test

service sendmail restart
```

If, however, you are those that directly edit the .cf instead of the .mc then you’ll have to do the following

In you .cf find the following text (“Msmtp,” , “Mesmtp,” , “Mdsmtp, “, “Mrelay,”)
After that find the following line(s)

T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,
And change it to look like this

r=1, T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,
Explanation:

This problem isn’t really an error as it requests your emails when this happens.
Though the third solution will work is not ideal to use as it requires sendmail to open/close connections for each email.
One last thing to look for is the cached-connections for sendmail

ConnectionCacheSize
ConnectionCacheTimeout

Link: 
http://dynobin.com/google-mx-multiple-domains-unsupported/